# Late-90s book about teenagers who transform into supernatural creatures

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a book I read as a young boy mid 90's to very early 2000's, I believe. It featured a team of teen humans who had the ability to transform into various supernatural creatures.

I believe the setting was based in the United States or at least North America.

I remember vividly two characters:

1. There was a lycanthrope , I remember a name... which is either Kodiak or Kody/Cody. I believe this character also had a love interest within the team.
2. There was a character who was stereotype alien-like (thin with large head), but I believe was a ghoul or demon of some sorts that is noted to cause accidents in North America. I cannot quite remember if this was a creature in the fictional universe or one of the teens could transform into it. I believe it might be the [Dover Demon](http://cryptidz.wikia.com/wiki/Dover_Demon).

I also remember that the cover, the first few or last pages or so had a list of the creatures and short profiles.

Comment: have you had any luck? ive been trying to think of the same book i think but cant find it!

Comment: Nothing so far! I am hoping that at some point in my lifetime the right person comes across this question. hahaha.

Answer (score 5):

There's two posibilities I know of:

- [Animorphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animorphs). A team of human teens (and one alien) able to shapeshift into different animals, battling an alien invasion. Not supernatural entities, but it does take place in the USA.
- [Switchers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switchers_Trilogy). Human teens able to shapeshift into supernatural characters. Takes place in Ireland, though.

No Kodiak/Kody/Cody, though, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks Dr McCoy, It wasn't the animorphs and it doesn't seem to be switchers either.

Comment: Okay, then I don't know, sorry. Good luck finding what you're looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

Might be the [Mind Warp](https://www.goodreads.com/series/61016-mindwarp) series, the first book was called Alien Terror.

Comment: Not the Mind warp series. Thanks however for a potential good read.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the Strange Forces series, which was a spin-off of the Strange Matter series. Hope this is what you're looking for!

Comment: Can you provide any sources or links to your story? Or any bits of text that show its similarities.

Comment: Please see [our guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9445/31394) on how to write a good answer to a story-ID question.